# Problem with babel, ragged2e and parbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, babel, ragged2e

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \parbox{9cm}{
      \textsc{
Jesus a dit~: \og Je suis le bon berger~;
 le bon berger donne sa vie pour les brebis \fg{}
      }
    }
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

The paragraph usually gives good results, but with this specific sentence, I get something ugly:

[image: ragged2e with babel]

The case is quite rare (I have tens of other boxes that work fine) so I could just force the carriage return for this one, but I'd like to understand why it does this...

Comment: I don't get the same output; instead, the second instance of the word "berger" is split as "ber-ger".

Comment: @egreg: that'd be better indeed if such was the case for me.

Comment: @Raphink: are you sure that French hyphenation is enabled? Is that really the example?

Comment: @egreg: It is really the example, as is, built with `pdflatex`, under Ubuntu Lucid, without any options. Nothing added, nothing removed.

Comment: Look at the log for possible messages about missing hyphenation patterns

Comment: Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for
(babel)                the language `French'
(babel)                I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead.
 indeed. Why would that happen?

Comment: Alright, I was missing the `texlive-lang-french` package. Thanks for pointing out in the right direction.

Comment: The line break after `\textsc{` is adding a space before 'Jesus'. To avoid this either use `%`, i.e. `\textsc{%`, to make LaTeX ignore the line break or avoid the line break altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it certainly is better if you activate the hyphenation pattern for french. This will "split" the berger. It also helps if you remove the stretchable space in the spacing command inserted by `\og`. But the main problem is that the centering commands of `ragged2e` changes the spaceskip but doesn't reset it at the start of the `\parbox`. This forces LaTeX to stretch the only stretchable space available (after the \og) as much as possible. I would say this is a bug.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[newcommands]{ragged2e}
\makeatletter
% \def\FBguill@spacing{\penalty\@M\hskip.8\fontdimen2\font}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\parbox{9cm}{%
    \lipsum[1]\par
    \scshape
     Jesus a dit~: \og Je suis le bon berger~;
     le bon berger donne sa vie pour les brebis \fg{}
    }


\begin{center}
   \parbox{9cm}{%
   \lipsum[1]\par
    \scshape
   Jesus a dit~: \og Je suis le bon berger~;
   le bon berger donne sa vie pour les brebis \fg{}
    }
\end{center}

\makeatletter 
%correcting the spaceskips:

\begin{center}
  \parbox{9cm}{%
    \@raggedtwoe@spaceskipfalse
    \@raggedtwoe@everyselectfont
    \lipsum[1]\par
    \scshape
   Jesus a dit~: \og Je suis le bon berger~;
   le bon berger donne sa vie pour les brebis \fg{}
    }
\end{center}

\end{document}
```