# My spaces are swallowed

Tags: soul, ragged2e

I want to have my code examples show up with not only `\code{\textbackslash texttt}` but also a grey box. You might be familiar with the looks from some famous web page with questions and answers on LaTeX somewhere :). However when my code contains spaces like for example `\code{some other code}` the spaces seem to be swallowed. This seem to be related to the loaded packages somehow. What can I do about it?

```
\documentclass[oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcommand\code[1]{\hl{\texttt{#1}}}
\definecolor{mygrey}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.05}
\sethlcolor{mygrey}
\begin{document}
\noindent
I want to have my code examples show up with not only \code{\textbackslash texttt} but also a
grey box. You might be familiar with the looks from some famous web page with
questions and answers on \LaTeX\ somewhere :). However when my code contains spaces
like for example \code{some other code} the spaces seem to be swallowed. This
seem to be related to the loaded packages somehow. What can I do about it?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think `\hl` can't cope with `\texttt` inside it. Try changing their order: `\texttt{\hl{#1}}`.

Comment: Can confirm Phelypes suggestion works just fine.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436849/2388, that's the same problem and the change in ragged2e works too.

Answer (score 5):

Using `\ttfamily` outside of the soul macro works:

```
\documentclass[oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\newcommand\code[1]{{\ttfamily \hl{#1}}}
\definecolor{mygrey}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.05}
\sethlcolor{mygrey}
\begin{document}
\noindent
I want to have my code examples show up with not only \code{\textbackslash texttt} but also a
grey box. You might be familiar with the looks from some famous web page with
questions and answers on \LaTeX\ somewhere :). However when my code contains spaces
like for example \code{some other code} the spaces seem to be swallowed. This
seem to be related to the loaded packages somehow. What can I do about it?
\end{document}
```

[image]